# Html <i> Tag Button Not Fully Clickable

Tags: javascript, html, css

I made a [Hamburger Menu Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KnXW9.png) for my website. I used the  tag in html and css to design it. I used javascript to make it clickable, except there is a problem. Only the first line of the menu button is clickable. I noticed when I go into Inspect Element on my site it changes:

```
`.box-shadow-menu {
    position: absolute;
    padding-right: 1px;
    width: 25px;
    height: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
}`
```

to

```
`.box-shadow-menu {
    position: absolute;
    padding-right: 20px;
}`
```

Then if I paste in the correct code it works correctly.

```js
function ViewsDisplay1() {
    var x = document.getElementById("ViewCountDisplay");
    if (x.style.display === "none") {
        x.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        x.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

```css
/* Menu Button Below*/

.box-shadow-menu {
    position: absolute;
    padding-right: 1px;
    width: 25px;
    height: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.box-shadow-menu:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  right: 0;
  top: 0.25em;
  width: 1em;
  height: 0.15em;
  background: black;
  box-shadow: 
    0 0.25em 0 0 black,
    0 0.5em 0 0 black;
}

.SettingsButton1{
    position:absolute;
    right: 25px;
    top:8px;
    padding: 9px 10px;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
  <div id="NavBar">
   <nav>
    <div class="Search1">
     <div class="inputWithIcon">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Channel ID" id="chnlname">
      <i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true" id="update"></i>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="SettingsButton1">
     <i class="box-shadow-menu" aria-hidden="true" id="button" onclick="ViewsDisplay1()"></i>
    </div>
             <ul id="list1">
                 <li><a href="#">Liker</a></li>
                 <li><a href="index.html">Live Count</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Logan IS Dumb</a></li>
             </ul>
       </nav>
  </div>
```

Comment: HMM, I really don't know. Working for me in chrome on mac. What happens if you add a `top: 0 /right: 0` value to box-shadow-menu and not just the ::before ?

Comment: (since my answer was no good I just deleted it and thought I'd carry on the conversation here!)

Comment: @RoseRobertson Hey! I was wondering if I could see your full code, I want to see if I get your results. If it works then I will know there is something else in my code affecting the menu! Thanks!!

Comment: I was actually just running the code you pasted directly from stackoverflow!

Comment: @RoseRobertson I ended up getting it to work with your first suggestion, I have no idea why it did not work off the bat. Thanks, for your help!